# Devise block confirmation if email is not in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, devise-confirmable

I am running a Rails 5 app with devise. There recently has been a multitude of confirmation requests for bogus emails after receiving hits to the site from Russia. I assume that this is a bot since I have been receiving all of the undeliverable email notifications for these emails.

How can I stop the emails from being sent out if there is no record in the database for that user email?

Devise snippet per request...

users/beengie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/devise/...confirmations_controller.rb

```
# POST /resource/confirmation
def create
  self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(resource_params)
  yield resource if block_given?

  if successfully_sent?(resource)
    respond_with({}, location: after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
  else
    respond_with(resource)
  end
end
```

My try at wrapping the method to prevent it. Still don't know if it is working yet.

app/controllers/users/confirmation_controller.rb

```
# POST /resource/confirmation
def create
  if User.exists?(email: params[:user][:email])
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey @Beengie i think  you're sending Confirmation email on successfully creating an user so, before calling the mailer add a conditional check like `@user.email.exists?` .

Comment: I tried testing that, but it seems that devise already has a block if the email doesn't exist. I need to edit the question since somehow there are emails being sent with no email record in the users database.

Comment: can you post code snippet where you are calling the confirmation mailer so that it explains where the issue is?

Comment: It is standard devise gem. I wrapped the super in the create method looking for the params[:user][:email] and checked to see if it exists. User.exists?(params[:user][:email]). I hope that will fix it. I will add the devise snippet.